# Loading Page export tool for mobile app

Tags: android, iphone, ios, image, mobile

Does anyone know of a tool that takes an image or images and exports it to all the various iPhone and android size specifications?

Recreating all the minor variations is a bear.  I was looking a phatch as a possible solution, but wanted to see if there was already something written.

Answer (score 0):

I know of an iOS Only App that helps in the creation of HD/SD Images for iPhone by a simple drag and drop, can check it out in the Mac AppStore, called ShipIt! http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shipit!/id492043869?mt=12

As for android I do not know.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot on the next release!